# Select menu that filters a table by rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectmenu

Can anyone take a look my fiddle and let me know where I'm going wrong? I just want to check the second column in the table, and if it contains any of the words in the select menu that is chosen, it should show that row.

http://jsfiddle.net/fuelishways/sEUSn/

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your if statement to this:

```
if (check && check.indexOf(letter) > 0) {
    $(this).parent().show();
}
```

Your condition was true only if the selected value was not fond (== instead of >). Also, to fetch the parent inside an each() loop you always need to refer to the current object.

In your website you need to wrap the code inside `$( document ).ready()` event. Try this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    jQuery('select.filterMe').change( function(e) { 
       var letter = jQuery(this).val();
         if (letter === 'ALL') {
             jQuery('tr').show ();
         }
         else {
             jQuery('tr').each( function(rowIdx,tr) {
                 jQuery(this).hide().find('td').each( function(idx, td) {
                     if( idx === 0 || idx === 1) {
                         var check = jQuery(this).text();
                         if (check && check.indexOf(letter) > 0) {
                            jQuery(this).parent().show();
                        } 
                     }
                 });             

             });
         }             
     });​
 });​
```

Comment: that seemed to work, in the fiddle, but when i move it over to my web page at http://visitkoko.edventura.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5&Itemid=5, it doesn't work. any ideas?

Comment: any chance you could take a look at this fiddle? i'm trying to filter it down to show the li based on the drop down.
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/fuelishways/hu3A2/)